# C++ regex finds only 1 sub match

Tags: c++, regex

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>
int main()
{
 std::string strr("1.0.0.0029.443");

    std::regex rgx("([0-9])");
    std::smatch match;

    if (std::regex_search(strr, match, rgx)) {
        for(int i=0;i<match.size();i++)
            std::cout << match[i] << std::endl;
    }
}
```

this program should write

```
1
0
0
0
0
2
9
4
4
3
```

but it writes

```
1
1
```

checked it here http://cpp.sh/ and on visual studio, both same results.

Why does it find only 2 matches and why are they same?

---

As I understand from answers here, regex search stops at first match and match variable holds the necessary (sub?)string value to continue(by repeating) for other matches. Also since it stops at first match, `()` charachters are used only for sub-matches within the result.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Being called once, `regex_search` returns only the first match in the `match` variable. The collection in `match` comprises the match itself and capture groups if there are any.

In order to get all matches call `regex_search` in a loop:

```
while(regex_search(strr, match, rgx))
{
    std::cout << match[0] << std::endl;
    strr = match.suffix();
}
```

Note that in your case the first capture group is the same as the whole match so there is no need in the group and you may define the regex simply as `[0-9]` (without parentheses.)

Demo: https://ideone.com/pQ6IsO

Comment: Why does it put only 1 search match into match variable? It stops searching at first match?

Comment: `\\d` is a slightly shorter alternative to `[0-9]`

Comment: thank you for this important information.

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik: I think you're misunderstanding what the match variable is for. It is not for holding multiple matches. It is for holding matching sub-groups within the match (groups specified in parenthesis).

Comment: If I want to find three floating point variables, I need to loop for 3 times then, if I understand correctly. (ofcourse with proper regex code)

Answer (score 1):

Problems:

1. Using `if` only gives you one match. You need to use a `while` loop to find all the matches. You need to search past the previous match in the next iteration of the loop.
2. `std::smatch::size()` returns 1 + number of matches. See [its documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_search). `std::smatch` can contain sub-matches. To get the entire text, use `match[0]`.

Here's an updated version of your program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>

int main()
{
   std::string strr("1.0.0.0029.443");

   std::regex rgx("([0-9])");
   std::smatch match;

   while (std::regex_search(strr, match, rgx)) {
      std::cout << match[0] << std::endl;
      strr = match.suffix();
   }
}
```

Comment: I guess there is no one-liner as in C# to get all parts with string.Split(stringArray,..)

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik, I haven't programmed in C#. I can't respond to that.